# How to use flutter NestedScrollView?

Tags: flutter, nestedscrollview

I implemented some `NestedScrollView` as below. 
It causes an error "must be called with a context that contains a NestedScrollView".
But I used `Builder` to build the widget, and that is in the manual of flutter docs. What should I do?

```dart
return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, isInScroll) {
        /* something*/
      },
      body: Hero(
        tag: widget.folderInfo.title + 'body',
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 20.0, 16.0, 16.0),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              print("built body builder");
               // below line causes error "must be called with a context that contains a NestedScrollView"
              var handle =
                  NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context);
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Builder` function expects a return statement which seems to be missing from code you provided.

Below code works and prints `test` on screen:

```
return NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar()
            ];
          },
          body: Hero(
            tag: 'test',
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 20.0, 16.0, 16.0),
              child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                var handle = NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context);
                print('test');
                return Container( . // whatever you want to return here
                 child: Text('test'),
                );
                print('test');

              })
            ),
          ),
    );
```